# Jupyter Notebook - failed to start kernel. Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have just set up a venv in python and installed ipykernel. When trying to execute a cell in a notebook (a simple print("Hello world")), I get the following error:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100). 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

I'm using the following versions fo ipykernel and pyzmq:

```
ipykernel - 6.25.1
pyzmq - 25.1.1
```

Any idea what can be happening here?

Thank you in advance for your help!